# PHP function to get the same output depending on input

Tags: php, arrays, string, function

I have more than 30.000 items (as string). And I have an array with 10 elements.
I want to associate each item to an element of array. So, more or less, 3.000 items will be associated to first element, 3.000 items to the second element, etc...
This must be random, but the function always has to assign the same output depending on the input.
For example, every time we run the function the string "345hdsf" have to be associated to the same element of the array. And the string "oiu85dsf" may have to be associated to a different one (but every time the same).

The input string could be any string. I don't know the value of the input strings and can increase the number of strings in time.

Is that possible with PHP? Maybe do I have to use some encrypting method?

Comment: you could use encryption or hashing I guess. Hashing probably makes more sense as it's a one-way process. And then use a predictable sequence of salt values to vary the output for each element of the array.

Comment: Not sure how ___This must be random___ and ___but the function always has to assign the same output depending on the input___
 can fit together in a single sentence

Comment: @RiggsFolly Sorry, what I mean is that if there are 30,000 items and 10 possible elements, that 1 of these 10 element is chosen randomly, but that it is the same output depending on the same input value. I do not know if I explain correctly my idea.

Comment: I think thats better

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your key requirement here is that the process is *repeatable*. It might look random to a human, but the process for deciding which "bucket" each element falls in very much needs to be stable.

What you're looking for (as people have mentioned in the comments) is a hashing function that will output one of 10 keys - your required number of buckets. The easiest way I can of doing this with PHP is to grab the remainder of a [`crc32`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.crc32.php) hash mod 10:

```
$key = crc32($string) % 10;
```

You can then assign the element to that bucket in the output:

```
$buckets = [];

foreach ($strings as $string) {
    $key = crc32($string) % 10;

    $buckets[$key][] = $string;
}
```

See https://3v4l.org/enEEV

The results aren't perfect by any means (in that example the buckets have anywhere from 5 to 14 elements), but it will even out with larger input sizes. Bucket counts for 30,000 elements look like this:

```
0 - 3099
1 - 3085
2 - 2930
3 - 2975
4 - 2983
5 - 2969
6 - 2981
7 - 2987
8 - 2921
9 - 3070
```

Comment: Thank you! Great answer